# MS Excel: Formula for latest date values with conditions (Date / category / balance amount)

Tags: excel, formula

I'm searching for a formula that could give me the up to date balance amount (which the total balance would be updated each time that I will add transactions on an account (tab name "Épargnes-Inv."). I've put a link for each tabs that are related.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDibY.png)

For example:
TODAY (january-14-2021):The latest balance for the account "RED" is 260.00$.
February 8th-2021: I add 40$ for the RED account (total balance would be now 300.00$)
This is where I would enter the formula (tab "Solde comptes."):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNuTH.png)
Thanks in advance for your feedback!!

Answer (score 0):

With function =SUMIFS you can set multiple conditions.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1johx.png)

Edit(20.01.2021) : Ok, I see my error, I mixed the two images. I'll try again.

With SUMIFS, the first criteria selects all the amounts related to the same account, but if you add the second criteria you get ONLY the amounts related to the same account that has a date equals of "before" his date. So if you search for "today" balance then replace the 2nd criteria with TODAY() function.

=SUMIFS(Sheet2!$E$2:$E$13,Sheet2!$D$2:$D$13,"="&Sheet1!B4,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$13,"<="&TODAY())

[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhTrL.png)

Comment: Hi Heap! If I'm not mistaking, SUMIFS yes I can put conditions but at the end, it will sum up all the amounts related to the same account. What I look for is to search only the latest date by reference of today with his balance. Thanks for trying to help though (y)